# Capture result output of send query in RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, r-s4, rsqlite

I would like to log the the number of rows changed when doing an update to a table in SQLite using RSQLite.

This:

```
dbSendQuery(db, "UPDATE FOO SET BAR = 1 WHERE BAZ = 0)
```

Returns an S4 object:

```
<SQLiteResult>
SQL UPDATE FOO SET BAR = 1 WHERE BAZ = 0
ROWS Fetched: 0 [Complete]
     Changed: 11965
```

When I store the S4 object, I can call most of the content it seems (for example example_S3@sql provides the pure SQL code), but I can't get at the "Changed" bit (see above), which I'd like to log.

Any help is appreciated, limited SQL experience I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.4-1/topics/dbGetRowsAffected) you want the `dbGetRowsAffected` function

> **The number of rows affected**
>
> This function returns the number of rows that were added, deleted, or
>   updated by data modifying query. For a selection query, this function
>   returns 0.